# Qt Application Deploying in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

This is very messy situation that I have got.
Before posting this into StackOverFlow, I have looked into all solutions provided in net. But none of those help.

I have created a small application for my professor, and now when I have build the executable code in my PC, the application never runs. It says, I need some .dll file.

Once if I attach the .dll files into the package, everything works perfect, except one thing, the application size which was supposed to be around few 20-30 kb goes to 1.23Gb.

My question is how to solve the issues? Can anyone give me a solution in a very simple-feasible way?

I need to link those .dll file but also need to keep the application small enough to make it portable.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577808/deploying-qt-application), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774724/deploying-a-qt-application-on-windows), and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment), and also [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/deployment-windows.html) and finally [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git); none of them helped!

Comment: ' 20-30 kb' is an unrealistically small expectation for a complete Windows GUI app.

Comment: ok. then lets say upto 5 - 20 MB. Then? How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You would only need to redistribute the release version of your application, which links to the release version of the Qt DLLs, which are 5-20 MB in size, depending on the Qt version, compiler, and used modules.

Comment: rubenvd How to do this? Please guide/any link!